# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.util.Map

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am getting the error in this line: "Map map = (Map) dataSnapshot.getValue();"

```
     private void getAssignedCustomer(){
    String driverId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference assignedCustomerRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Drivers").child(driverId);
    assignedCustomerRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

                Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                if(map.get("customerRideId") != null){
                    customerId = map.get("customerRideId").toString();
                    getAssignedCustomerPickupLocation();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

How to get rid of this error???

Comment: Share code of "DataSnapshot" class.

Comment: where do I get this?

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue()

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the Firebase documentation:

> getValue() returns the data contained in this snapshot as native types. The possible types returned are:
>
> Boolean
>
> String
>
> Long
>
> Double
>
> Map
>
> List
>
> This list is recursive; the possible types for Object in the above list is given by the same list. These types correspond to the types available in JSON.

The value returned from `dataSnapshot.getValue()` seems to be **Boolean**, and it cannot certainly be assigned to a `Map<String, Object>`.

Make sure that you are using the correct data from `dataSnapshot`

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code

```
if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
  String avataStr = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First check in your firabase database that the value for the key driverId that you are trying to retrieve under your node Users/Drivers is not a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you solved the problem, if not, use this code:

```
private void getAssignedCustomer(){
String driverId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference assignedCustomerRef = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users")
 .child("Drivers").child(driverId).child("customerRideId");
assignedCustomerRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
             customerId = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
             getAssignedCustomerPickupLocation();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

}